# Change ticks number on a subplot with MaxNLocator - ticks vanish

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels, subplot

I'm creating several subplots in python 3 (I think) with matplotlib in a `for` loop, and I want to set the NUMBER of `yticks/ xticks`, because the max and min values vary with each loop. 
I've tried using the MaxNLocator as suggested in this answer [change ticks number on a subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425974/change-ticks-number-on-a-subplot#comment43295117_27426087)
(I'm sorry to ask another question about this now, but I couldn't comment on the answer given there):

```
from matplotlib import ticker
M = 3
yticks = ticker.MaxNLocator(M)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(yticks)
```

But this doesn't work for me. The `yticklabels` and `yticks` just vanish completely on the subplots in the `for` loop and I get two `xticks` although I requested five. The one subplot outside the `for` loop still has `yticklabels` but a different number of ticks than requested. 
And I am NOT using a logarithmic axis on either!
I'd be great, if anyone had an idea, how to fix this! :)

The structure of my code is:

```
f = plt.figure(figsize =(13,10),dpi=300)

yticks = ticker.MaxNLocator(4)    # number of yticks
xticks = ticker.MaxNLocator(5)    # number of xticks
yfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d.%m.\n%H:%M')    # format of date

for n,m in enumerate (['20-25cm','15-20cm','10-15cm','5-10cm','0-5cm']):
    ax = f.add_subplot(6,1,-n+6)    # subplots number 6 to number 2

    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(yticks)    # <-- ?
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xticks)    # <-- ?
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)    # format for date on xaxis
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)    
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
    if n !=0:
        ax.set_xticklabels([])    # only put xtlabels at the bottom subplot

    Y = dictionary[data][n][:]    
    #Y is a np.array with floats from a dictionary

    X = dictionary[date][n][:]    
    #X is a np.array containing datetime objects from the same dictionary

    plt.plot(X[-250:-1],Y[-250:-1], label = m)


ax1 = f.add_subplot(6,1,1)    # subplot number 1 outside the loop
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
ax1.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)    
ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(yticks)    # <-- ?
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(xticks)    # <-- ?
ax1.set_xticklabels([])

plt.scatter(X[-250:-1],poolA[-250:-1])    # poolA,B,C are just np.arrays
plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(X[-250:-1],poolB[-250:-1])
plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(X[-250:-1],poolC[-250:-1]) 

plt.savefig('figure.pdf',format = 'pdf', dpi=f.dpi)
```

Comment: It seems you are working with dates on the xaxis. This makes things more complicated. Please provide a [mcve] (a runnable code) of the issue to work on. Also note that `MaxNLocator` set the maximum number of bins. Hence you may always end up with less than the number given to it (it's really maxN, not N itself).