# Plotting with marplotlib does not show all items in list

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey I have a bit of a weird issue with matplotlib, I have this function:

```
def line_plot(results):
    gen_eight = all_of_g(results, 8)
    gen_sixteen = all_of_g(results, 16)
    gen_thirty_two = all_of_g(results, 32)
    print(len(gen_eight))
    print(len(gen_sixteen))
    print(len(gen_thirty_two))

    N = 12


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    #ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
    #width = 0.15         # the width of the bars

    plt.plot(gen_eight)
    plt.plot(gen_sixteen)
    plt.plot(gen_thirty_two)

    ax.set_xticklabels(('1MB', '4MB', '8MB', '10MB', '16MB', '32MB', '64MB', '100MB', '128MB', '256MB', '512MB', '1GB'))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

But what it plots is what you seen in the image below and the three twelves are the prints of the length. So missing half the values.

[image]

What I find really weird is that this function

```
def bar_plot(results):

    gen_eight = all_of_g(results, 8)
    gen_sixteen = all_of_g(results, 16)
    gen_thirty_two = all_of_g(results, 32)

    print(gen_eight)


    N = 12


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
    width = 0.30         # the width of the bars
    p1 = ax.bar(ind, gen_eight, width, color='r')
    p2 = ax.bar(ind+width, gen_sixteen, width, color='y')
    p3 = ax.bar(ind+width+width, gen_thirty_two, width, color='b')



    #ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
    ax.set_xticklabels(('1MB', '4MB', '8MB', '10MB', '16MB', '32MB', '64MB', '100MB', '128MB', '256MB', '512MB', '1GB'))

    plt.xticks(rotation=75)

    ax.legend((p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]), ('g=8', 'g=16','g=32'))
    ax.autoscale_view()
    plt.ylabel('time (ms)')
    plt.xlabel('Data Size')
    plt.yscale("log", nonposy='clip')
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig('NOT_SHOWING')

    plt.show()
```

Works and plots the figure as it is supposed to. I hope someone can help me

[image]

Comment: Note that from the picture and the code shown it is hard to see if anything is wrong or not. If you can provide a runnable [mcve], one can sure look into it. What happens if you add a marker to the plots, `plt.plot(gen_eight, marker="o")`? How many markers are there?

Comment: eh there is 12 plot ...

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a picture that shows it

Comment: and it basically just list of floating points

Comment: Yes, but you see 12 points. So it's doing everything as expected.

Comment: I think this should work fine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27425974/9119615

Comment: There are 12 points on your first image, it's just harder to see them without the individual marks. Look at the right, the line bends once between each X position.

Comment: Possibly the solution to this is in a totally different direction. As a rule of thumb: Don't ever use `set_ticklabels` without specifying `set_ticks` as well, as in don't just tell matplotlib which labels you want, also tell it where to put them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ... thank you found the solution